# What's the difference between @CascadeOnDelete and CascadeType.REMOVE annotations?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

At first I've expected that with `CascadeType.REMOVE` I'll be able to delete foreign keys in my table , but I sill got an exception. But with `@CascadeOnDelete` it's ok .What's the difference between the two annotations?

*EDIT:* I've saw the DataNucleus' comment.Cascade on delete comes from `org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.CascadeOnDelete` .Which raises the question how good idea is to be used.

Comment: @CascadeOnDelete is not part of JPA, so suggest you mention where it comes from

Comment: the exception was: `DELETE on table 'XXX' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'YYY' for key (xxx).  The statement has been rolled back.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use CascadeType.Remove at the time the cascading will be handled by the ORM tool  but when you want the cascading to be handled by the database you can use  @CascadeOnDelete.but when you are using @CascadeOnDelete , make sure the Database you are using should support cascading.

Comment: It depends on how you are using it.if you want your code to be strictly compliant with JPA specification then you should not use CascadeOnDelete.But if you are sure that if wont be changing your JPA provider then it may be useful to use CascadeonDelete. For more information you can refer [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DeleteCascade)

Comment: I also think CascadeOnDelete should be performing way better, because CascadeType.ALL will trigger hundreds of queries to delete each entry, whereas with CascadeOnDelete only one query happens.